# Facebook sandbox breakdowns

Tags: sandbox, facebook-marketing-api

Does facebook Marketing API SANDBOX support breakdowns like age, gender?

When I try to make request I get only empty list. Maybe I make something wrong?
I try:

```
/version/act_<ad_account_id>/insights?
fields=spend,impressions&breakdowns=age,gender
```

When I delete breakdowns, sandbox return normal data like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "spend": "20",
      "impressions": "200",
      "date_start": "2017-10-16",
      "date_stop": "2017-11-14"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MAZDZD",
      "after": "MAZDZD"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They did not, until today. It was a bug and it has been resolved.

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/371158323621879/